# How do I keep track the number of times a specific input was entered by the user?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

My program should ask the user to enter some grades. After the input is finished, the program has to show which grade was entered how many times (or in another word, how many times each grade was entered).

For example, if the user enters grade 3 two times, thats menas total 2 students has got the grade 3. If the grade F is entered 3 times, that means 3 students has got the failing grade F, and so on....

The final output should look something like this:

```
    Example output: 
grade F= 3 students
grade 3= 2 studnets
and so on....
...........................
...........................
```

**Now my problem is with keeping track of each grade and print them out telling how many times (also means how many students got each specific grade) each of the grade was entered. I can't come up with idea to solve it.**

My code:

```
    package studentgrade;

import java.util.*;

public class StudentGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many total grade you want to enter (Depending on the total number of students)? ");
        int totalStudents = input.nextInt();
        String grade[] = new String[totalStudents];

        //asking user to enter grade
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter grade " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            System.out.println("Choose only between grade 3 and F:\n");

            grade[i] = input.next();
            if (grade[i] == "3") {//3 defines the only passing grade
                //Store that into a variable
            } else if (grade[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {//F defines the failing grade

                //Store that into a variable
            }//else{
            //System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
            //}
        }
        //Now print out which grade was entered how many times
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to use additional arrays to store how many students got a specific grade.

Comment: You can use an int array and each index represents a grade. When user enter a new grade, increment 1 the value of element in index of this grade.

Comment: Or you could dump all the grades into one array or `ArrayList`, and then just count the number of each type later when you need to know it.

Comment: Use a HashMap with the key being the grade.

Comment: @demostene you would also need to store a count.  I guess you meant the key is the grade and the value is the count?

Comment: Also,You can't compare two strings with `==`. Use `.equals()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define, at the top, a variable resembling each grade and set them to 0, and then, each time in the "if" statement, add one to the corresponding variable. *variable++*.

At the end, use

```
  System.out.println("Grade 3: " + variable3);
    System.out.println("Grade F: " + variableF);
```

Also, use .equals method to compare two strings in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the sort of introduced values, simply create an array with your needed size `n` (don't see exactly what means from 3 to F).

```
int[] grade = new int[n];
```

If all inputs where numbers you can make direct:

```
grade[input.next()] ++;
```

Then, as all inputs are not `int` you can solve it with a switch

```
switch(input.next()) {
     case "3":
          grade[0] ++;
     case "2":
          grade[1] ++;
     ....
     case "F":
          grade[n-1] ++;

 }
```

Comment: Input.next() returns a string, so _case 3:_ would have to be _case "3":_

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for a `Map`. Right now your only storing the inputs `3` and `F` but if you wanted to adapt this program to have more grades this would scale perfectly and it is a clean and neat solution.

```
// the map to store how many times a grade was entered
private static final Map<String, Integer> gradeSumMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void addToGradeSum(String key, int num) {
    if(gradeSumMap.get(key) == null) {
        gradeSumMap.put(key, num);
    } else {
        gradeSumMap.put(key, gradeSumMap.get(key) + num);
    }
}

public static void printGradeSumMap() {
    for(String key : gradeSumMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("grade " + key + " = " + gradeSumMap.get(key));
    }
}

// this needs to also be .equals or .equalsIgnoreCase
if (grade[i].equals("3")) {
    addToGradeSum(grade[i], 1);
} else if (grade[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
    addToGradeSum(grade[i], 1);
}
```

then just call `printGradeSumMap()` when you want to print it